# Cannot Convert from const int* to int*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the following piece of code, but I'm getting a C2440 (visual studio) error. I've tried looking at other resources for help, but I can't find a good explanation.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    SomeFunction(&a);
}

void SomeFunction(const int* value)
{
    //This line of code gives me the error. 
    int* variable = value;

    cout << "Value is " << *Variable << " end" << endl;
}
```

I know I can solve this problem by using `int* variable = const_cast<int*> (value);`, but I still don't understand why the above code is causing a problem.

Comment: Try: `const int* variable = value;`

Comment: *Why* would you want to convert a `const int*` to non-const?

Comment: @DanielVoina Read the question he clearly says "I know I can use const_cast"

Comment: @DanielVoina Aaaw no! Not as long you're not knowing, what exactly you're doing, and why.

Comment: int* variable = (int*)value; - this also discards const-ness. It will make your code work. It's ugly though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error's quite clear - a pointer conversion can't remove a `const` qualifier; otherwise, you could violate the constness:

```
int* variable = value; // Not allowed - but if it were...
*variable = 42;        // BOOM! changed a constant.
```

If you don't want to be able to change the value being pointed at, then keep it `const`

```
const int* variable = value;
```

If you do want to change it, then don't make it `const` in the first place:

```
void SomeFunction(int* value)
```

> I know I can solve this problem by using `const_cast`

That's a bad idea - you'll get undefined behaviour if you abuse `const_cast` and try to modify a constant object. You should use `const` where you can, but not when you want to modify something.

Answer (score 12):

The `const int*` means that you have the address of an `int` that you are not allowed to change.

An `int*` can be used to change the `int` it points to.  Clearly that violates the above statement that you aren't allowed to change it.

`const_cast` does not actually "solve the problem".  It lets you request to change something which cannot be changed.  Such an attempt can cause your program to fail in uncontrolled ways (formally, undefined behavior).  In your particular example, the variable `a` in `main` is not `const`, and so `const_cast` will successfully change it.  But that creates close coupling and **contradicts the promise made by a function whose signature is `const int*`**.

Answer (score 2):

`int* variable = value;` is wrong.

It should be,

`int variable = *value`

and

`cout << "Value is " << variable << " end" << endl;`

Comment: This is a valid way to make a copy, which is rather different from the original code working with pointers.  Hard to say whether this is what "it should be".

Answer (score 1):

`const int *` means that the function guarantees that value at this address will not change, but if you can do:

```
int * variable = value;
```

Then you can also do

```
*variable=30;
```

In doing so, the guarantee of function that is of const pointer will be harmed.